# mysqli_fetch_object not return object

Tags: php, object, mysqli

Here is my query:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `page` AS p LEFT JOIN `page_settings` AS s ON p.id = s.page_id WHERE p.id = '".$this->id."'"));
echo $row->title;
```

This query returns error like this:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

But when I try this query:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE id = '".$this->id."'"));
echo $row->title;
```

It works perfectly. I understood nothing.

Comment: Your first query must be wrong.

Try running the query on your sql just to test it.
`SELECT * FROM page AS p LEFT JOIN page_settings AS s ON p.id = s.page_id WHERE p.id = '1'` 

What's the error?

Comment: Oh my pensive and tired head! `$this->id` is not set. So query returns error. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help!

I will comment an answer feel free to check it as the right answer to reward me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the `Trying to get property of non-object` error is because your query did not go through and therefore it's not an object, but an error message (or null at some cases).

So the answer is, **because your query failed.**